# fail to call REST end points using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest

i need to  integrate my App with other service by calling it's REST end points
am new to angularjs and i read the documention and i found this way which is not working for me i still dont get any data

```
var ltd = angular.module('mvDashboard', ['ngResource']);

ltd.factory('Ftd', function($resource){
        return $resource('https://external-domain/account/foremail/example@gmail.com');
    });

ltd.controller('mvPushCtrl',['$scope', function($scope, Push){
    Ftd.query(function(data){
        $scope.stuff= data;
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

this should return my account info on `"external-domain"` in `JSON` format i check this using post man 
but it doesn't work from my angular app, if any one have any idea ? also i wanna mention that i do this from local host i don't know if it's an issue? and, i also think this call must be done anytime i run the App true?

i would also post the code of my main module :

```
var myapp=angular.module('vascular'['ngResource','ngRoute','main','login','mvDashboard']);

myapp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider

        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: '/partials/main/main', 
            contorller: 'mvMainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/admin/users',{ 
            templateUrl: '/partials/admin/dashboard'
    });
});
```

I know this question answered many times and covered with many tutorials, but i tried so many solution and didn't work so i posted this question here

Comment: Is your API end point setup for CORS? Do you have any errors return by the server or display in the console?

Comment: Am calling API of other service that provide APIs , i check the console am getting no errors .

Answer (score 1):

In your controller , you have to inject your resource service.

```
//Ftd injected
ltd.controller('mvPushCtrl',['$scope','Ftd', function($scope,Ftd, Push){
    Ftd.query(function(data){
        $scope.stuff= data;
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: i fixed it and i also add the controller to the route '/partials/admin/dashboard', but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. you're injecting Push but using Ltd.
2. you forgot to annotate 'Push' so it's undefined
3. query on a resource object takes params as the first argument not the callback. Use

   res.query().$promise.then(function (data){});

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain to people who are new like me using angular.js what happen i read the ng-book CORS section because i thought i had CORS problem, and it works with this solution.

```
var myapp= angular.module('ltd', []);

    myapp.controller('mvLtdCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http){
        $http.jsonp("https://external-domain")
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.mydata = data;
            console.log(mydata);
        });
    }]);
```